# MySQL statement used in function stops working after first function call

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a PHP script which retrieves data from a MySQL database. Each table is a subject in math. The query is:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM $t WHERE  email='$currentEmail' AND username='$currentUser';";
```

where `$t` is the topic name from an array of topics:

```
$trial = array(
        'Algebra',
        'Computation',
        'Consumer_Arithmetic',
        'Geometry',
        'Matrices',
        'Measurement',
        'Number_Theory',
        'Relations',
        'Sets',
        'Statistics'
);
```

I then loop to query for each table in the array:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($trial); $i++) {
    chartist($trial[$i],$con,$currentUser,$currentEmail,&$chartone);
};
```

The function processes data, but it is only working for the first subject/table. The function is:

```
$chartone=array();

function chartist($t,$con,$currentUser,$currentEmail,&$chartone){
    $x=0;
    $y=0;
    $chartsub=array();

    $sqlquery="SELECT * FROM $t WHERE  email='$currentEmail' AND username='$currentUser';";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery);
    $resultfix=mysqli_num_fields($result);
    $resultfixed=$resultfix-2;
    $chartsub[]=$resultfixed;

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
    $arrlength=count($row);

    for($i=2;$i<$arrlength;$i++){
        if(0<$row[$i]){ 
            $x++;
            $y=$row[$i]+$y;
        }   
    }

    $chartsub[]=$x;
    $y=$y/($x);
    $chartsub[]=$y;
    $chartsub[]=$t;  
  ;
    $chartone[]=$chartsub;
    unset($t);

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);  
};
```

Why are all the iterations returning wrong values to JavaScript via the AJAX call?

**AJAX call function:**

```
function progress(){
    $('#progress').on('click', function(){
        if ($('#dataTarget').is(':parent')) {
            $('#dataTarget').hide().empty();
        }
        chart=true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/js/getScript.php',
            dataType:"json",
            data: {chart:chart},

            success: function(res){
                for(i=0;i<res.length;i++){
                    var fullcount=res[i][0];
                    var done=res[i][1];
                    var ave=res[i][2];
                    var dif=fullcount-done;
                    var doneper=done/fullcount*100;
                    var difper=dif/fullcount*100;
                    console.log(done);
                    console.log(fullcount);
                    console.log(ave);
                    console.log(res[0][0]);
                    console.log(res);
                    $('#dataTarget').append("<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-12'><h4>"+tp[i]+"<br>"+"Average score- "+Math.round(ave)+" %"+"</h4></div>");
                    $('#dataTarget div').last().append('<div class="ct-chart"></div>').attr('id', 'chart'+i);;
                    // applied to all divs in dataTarget
                    var sum = function(a, b) { return a + b };  
                    var data = {
                        labels: [Math.round(doneper)+"% Completed", Math.round(difper)+"% Uncompleted "],
                        series: [doneper,difper]
                    };
                    new Chartist.Pie('#chart'+i,data, {
                        chartPadding: 20,
                        labelOffset: 100,
                    });
                } 

                $('#dataTarget').velocity("transition.slideUpIn",1000); 
                if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 800){

                $('#dataTarget').append('<h2 class="col-sm-12" id="toTop">Back to the top</h2>');
                top();  
                down();         
            };                                  
            }
        });
    });
};
progress();
```

Comment: Where is your script? Your ajax call?

Comment: Also I couldn't find where you're echoing the result back to the javascript code

Comment: Why do you use multiple tables for this? An additional field in a single table would probably do better.

Comment: Why does the function chartist "take over ownership" of the $con parameter passed to it by closing the connection?

Comment: each topic has 6-11 excecises so i used a table for each topic

Comment: i added the js ajax call

Comment: It looks like you are closing your mysqli connection inside the function, is that needed/intentional? I'd imagine you need to either open a new connection, or keep that one open